# Using Javascript Regular Expression to Extract a Comment From Within a Function

Tags: javascript, regex

I am loading a js file via httprequest and attempting to parse a specific string (in this case a comment) from the resulting text, but am having trouble with the regular expression.

```
function SampleTest() {
    this.test1 = function() {
        /* :DOM <div id="sampleDIV">You loaded the sample div</div> */
    };
    this.test2 = function() {
        /* :DOM <div>Second Div Loaded</div> */          
    }
}
```

In another script I have the following functions:

```
var getElementFromComment = function(obj) {

    function getHTML(method) {
        var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.open('GET', 'SampleTest.js', false);
        httpRequest.send();
        var response = httpRequest.responseText;

        var re = new RegExp(method); //Not sure how to implement the regex
        var result = response.match(re);
        console.log(result);
    }

    for(var method in obj) {
        getHTML(method);
    }
}

var sampleTest = new SampleTest();
getElementFromComment(sampleTest);
```

The end result should be extracting the HTML from that comment in SampleTest based on the function name that is passed in. In my case I will be looping through all functions and retrieving the html string for each one after the other. I am assuming the proper approach would be to:

1. Get the Javascript file via httprequest - Already done
2. Find the function within SampleTest that matches the name passed
   into getHTML and return the entire function as a string via regex.
3. Use another regular expression to extract the string from within the
   function string starting with /* :DOM and ending with */ This should be able to be a multi-line comment even though for simplicity I am using only a single line.
4. And finally, replace all the garbage such as *'s and :DOM which
   should leave me with an html string.

I can't simply search the file for the comment off the bat because the file will likely contain multiple functions, each of which will have their own comment. To put this all in context, I am doing this because I want to be able to load HTML for javascript unit tests on the fly. The function will eventually loop through all functions in the unit test object, get the HTML, load it, run the function, remove the HTML, and move onto the next function.

**UPDATE**
Thanks to all the help from the accepted answers poster, I was able to get everything working. I did however have to make a few adjustments such as adding support for multi-line comments as well as replacing all the garbage characters after the fact so I could get a pure HTML string. My updated code is below.

```
function getHTML(method, str) {
        var commentMatch;
        var re = new RegExp(method+'\\s*=\\s*function[^}]+\\*/'); //Not sure how to implement the regex
        var fnMatch = str.match(re);
        if(fnMatch) {
            var fnEx = new RegExp('\/\*\s*:[^\s]+\s*(.*?|\n)\*\/', 'g');
            commentMatch = fnMatch[0].match(fnEx);
            var result = commentMatch[0].replace(/(\s*:DOM\s*)|(\*\/)|(\/\*)|(\*)/gm, '');
            result = result.replace(/^\s*/gm, '');
            if(commentMatch) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you realize that your ajax call is asynchronous and you can't just expect the result to be available after `.send()`? You need an `onreadystatechange` handler to know when the ajax call is actually done and the data is available.  So, I think you first need to fix step 1.

Comment: Thanks, I was just testing quickly and the results were returning so I hadn't gotten around to adding the onreadystatechange yet. Laziness, I know.

Comment: It would be easier if you used JSON for this, instead of trying to extract the info from the source code as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is to extract the comment string from a piece of javascript code in a javascript string variable, you can do that like this:

```
var str = "function SampleTest() { \
    this.test = function() { \
        /* :DOM <div id=\"sampleDIV\">You loaded the sample div</div> */ \
    }; \
}";

var matches = str.match(/\/\*\s*:DOM\s*(.*?)\*\//);
if (matches) {
    alert(matches[1]);
}​
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hWCwA/

---

If the ":DOM" part is not always the same, then you could use a slightly different version like this:

```
var str = "function SampleTest() { \
    this.test = function() { \
        /* :DOM <div id=\"sampleDIV\">You loaded the sample div</div> */ \
    }; \
}";

var matches = str.match(/\/\*\s*:[^\s]+\s*(.*?)\*\//);
if (matches) {
    alert(matches[1]);
}​
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/qpF3k/

---

OK, based on your comments, here's another shot at it.  This will find the next comment after the function name.  It will stop looking at the first `}` so it should not go into the next function if this one has no comment.

```
function findComment(funcName, str) {
    var commentMatch;
    var re = new RegExp("this\\." + funcName + "\\s*=\\s*function[^}]+\\*/");
    var funcMatch = str.match(re);
    if (funcMatch) {
        commentMatch = funcMatch[0].match(/\/\*\s*:[^\s]+\s*(.*?)\*\//);
        if (commentMatch) {
            return(commentMatch[1]);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is very close to answering my question. How would I begin getting the string at the function name and end at the end of the comment line regardless of how many lines the comment falls on?

Comment: @ryandlf - but point #3 in your question asked for the comment so that's what I wrote an algorithm to extract.  If you're asking for something else, you'll have to explain much better what you want.  What exactly do you want returned?  Please say exactly what text you want returned from this example.

Comment: Sorry, I reread and it was a little unclear. I am retrieving the "string" via http, so the entire source code of the sampletest is available as a string in the js code. The first will be to find the function name and then return the comment (multi-line) that appears next after that function. Reason being is because in production there will be many different functions in that class, each with or without a commented section that I will need to parse the html out of. Does that make sense?

Comment: Is there a way to find the function name but not include it in the match, and instead after finding that function name start parsing the first occurance of the /* :DOM until it reaches */, and multi-line is important here.

Comment: @ryandlf - which function name?  `SampleTest` or `test`?  Are you saying that the name "test" is passed in and you want to find the start of that function and then the next comment from there?

Comment: @ryandlf - OK, I added one more option to my answer that I think does what you want.  I won't be online for awhile now.